# Datastax Opscenter LCM Unable to Decrypt Passwords

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

We are trying to use encrypted passwords in cassandra and dse yaml files using opscenter LCM. We followed the instructions in below link

https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/sec/secEncryptProp.html?hl=encrypt,sensitive

It is throwing below error for us

```
INFO  05:54:39  Loading settings from file:/etc/dse/dse.yaml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfig.<clinit>(DseConfig.java:285)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseCoreModule.<init>(DseCoreModule.java:39)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.getRequiredModules(DseModule.java:98)
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.AbstractDseModule.configure(AbstractDseModule.java:26)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(DseModule.java:35)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:71)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Couldn't decrypt input
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfig.applyConfig(DseConfig.java:834)
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfig.<clinit>(DseConfig.java:278)
        ... 13 more
```

Below are the configurations from LCM:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your config_encryption_key_name is not set. Instructions are in the article you linked.

Comment: config_encryption_key_name  is set to system_key file which is created using this command "dsetool createsystemkey 'AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding' 128 system_key"